# Changing the category list order in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on editing a Wordpress plugin file.

The code below lists the categories in Alphabetical order. I want to list them by Category ID, in ascending order.

```
<?php foreach($categories as $category){ 
    $rand = rand(0,99);
    $catname = get_cat_name( $category );
    $find =     array("&", "/", " ","amp;","&#38;");
    $replace  = array("", "", "", "","");           
    $catname = str_replace($find,$replace,get_cat_name( $category ));
?>                  
    <li>
        <a href="#fragment-<?php echo $catname; ?>"><?php echo get_cat_name( $category ); ?></a>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
```

I tried working with the `get_cat_ID` function, but I'm not a programmer so I got stuck. Please help.

Comment: Can you post the output of 'echo print_r(array_keys($categories),true)' ?

Comment: Yes, here it is:

    Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 2
    )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than querying categories inside a theme file, a better way is to register a custom function in your wordpress theme.

Googling "wordpress category order by id" give me this link

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-order-my-categories-by-id-instead-of-name. The answer there is good.

```
add_filter('get_the_categories','get_the_category_sort_by_id');

function get_the_category_sort_by_id( $categories ) {
    usort($categories, '_usort_terms_by_ID');
    return $categories;
}
```

You can then call the function in your theme files which will return categories ordered by id. Something like that:

```
<?php
$categories = get_the_category_sort_by_id($categories);
foreach($categories as $category){ 
    ...
?>
    <li>
        <a href="#fragment-<?php echo $catname; ?>"><?php echo get_cat_name( $category ); ?></a>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Okay, I can insert that into functions.php, but I don't know how to change my original code to give me the list.

Please keep in mund that there's also the anchor given by the category name:

   <a href="#fragment-<?php echo $catname; ?>">

Comment: @Alex I've edited my answer. It's not tested but you will get the idea.

Comment: I tried putting it all together, but I only got errors...  

`Warning: Missing argument 1 for get_the_category_sort_by_id(), called in full-width-block.php on line 208 and defined in functions.php on line 5  
Warning: usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in functions.php on line 6  
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in full-width-block.php on line 209`